# How to use the new render pass API for an external renderer?

Tags: python, render-layers, external-applications, render-passes

I am developing an addon for an external renderer and want to register custom render passes.
Last time I implemented this feature I had to resort to images because Blender only had hardcoded render passes.

Nowadays the RenderEngine class offers several methods that seem to allow the registration of custom passes:

- [`register_pass(scene=None, srl=None, name="", channels=1, chanid="", type='VALUE')`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html?highlight=renderengine#bpy.types.RenderEngine.register_pass)
- [`update_render_passes(scene=None, renderlayer=None)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html?highlight=renderengine#bpy.types.RenderEngine.update_render_passes)
- [`add_pass(name, channels, chan_id, layer="")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html?highlight=renderengine#bpy.types.RenderEngine.add_pass)

However, I could not find any explanation or examples of how to use these methods. Looking at the Cycles source code also did not help much.

- Cycles implements the `update_render_passes` method: [https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/1d33843ea6b128242183bb31804474019c606a9d/intern/cycles/blender/addon/**init**.py#L105](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/1d33843ea6b128242183bb31804474019c606a9d/intern/cycles/blender/addon/__init__.py#L105)

  But I could not find out how or when this method is ever called. 
  When I implement this method in my addon, it is never called.
- In this implementation, it uses the `register_pass` method: https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/1d33843ea6b128242183bb31804474019c606a9d/intern/cycles/blender/addon/engine.py#L209

#### Where I currently am

I have managed to add a custom pass with the following code, which is currently executed in the constructor of my RenderEngine implementation:

`self.add_pass("Samplecount", 1, "X")`

It shows up in the image editor:

[image]

#### Problems/Questions

- The custom pass is always available in the image editor dropdown, even if it is not used in the current rendering
- It seems there is no method to remove or unregister a custom pass - how does Cycles do this?
- The custom pass does not show up in the compositor:
   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to brecht's explanation in IRC I can now answer my own question:

#### Custom passes in compositor

`update_render_passes` is called by the compositor to display the custom passes as output sockets. In this method, `register_pass` should be used.

Example:

```
def update_render_passes(self, scene=None, renderlayer=None):
    self.register_pass(scene, renderlayer, "Combined", 4, "RGBA", 'COLOR')

    aovs = scene.luxcore.aovs

    if aovs.samplecount:
        self.register_pass(scene, renderlayer, "Samplecount", 1, "X", 'VALUE')
    if aovs.shading_normal:
        self.register_pass(scene, renderlayer, "Shading_Normal", 3, "XYZ", 'VECTOR')
```

#### Custom passes in image editor

`add_pass` on the other hand should be called at the start of the `render` method to add custom passes (before writing data into a `render_result`).

Example:

```
# Note: the Depth pass is already added by Blender
# If you add it again, it won't be displayed correctly 
# in the "Depth" view mode of the "Combined" pass
# in the image editor.

aovs = scene.luxcore.aovs

if aovs.samplecount:
    self.add_pass("Samplecount", 1, "X")
if aovs.shading_normal:
    self.add_pass("Shading_Normal", 3, "XYZ")
```

I hope this helps other developers of addons for external render engines.