# Creating custom render passes

Tags: python, rendering

Working with the appleseed render engine and we are working on integrating AOV’s.  I’d like to import those AOV’s into custom render passes but I’m having trouble decoding how to create those passes as there are three different options in the RenderEngine types relating to it but no clear explanation on when they should be used (update_passes, register_passes and add_pass)

Comment: See my Q/A here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100791/how-to-use-the-new-render-pass-api-for-an-external-renderer

Comment: Beautiful. I didn’t find that thread but it looks good.

Comment: Works awesome BYOB.  One question though: is there any way that you know of to add a pass but not have it appear as an option in the image editor?  I'm interested in having a behind-the-scenes render pass that I can use for special cases but it should not be accessible to a user.

Comment: I don't think that's possible if you want to write it into a render result.
However you can always write your data into an array or a similar buffer and handle it your way.